# Define a variable before put it in objective function

Tags: matlab, optimization

My question is very clear.
I have an objective function in MATLAB. For example, i have f=@(x) (x(1)+x(2)*K) +something else.
Because the objective function is long and complex, i would like to define some variables beforehand and substitute them in objective function.
For example i would like to set M=x(1)+x(2) in order to write M*K in the objective function. 
I have tried M=@(x) x(1)+x(2) and substitute in objective function but did not work.
Any ideas please?
Regards

Answer (score 1):

If your objective function is complex, define it in a separate M-file, e.g:

```
function [out1 out2 out3] = complex_cost_fn(in1, in2, in3, in4, in5)

%%COMPLEX FUNCTION WITH MULTIPLE SUBFUNCTIONS

end

function cost1 = fn1(in1, in3, ..)
    .....
end

function gradients = fn2(in2, in4, ..)
    ....
end
```

Then define a handle:

```
my_cost = @(in1, in2, in3) complex_cost_fn(in1, in2, in3, in4, in5);
```

where "in1, in2, in3" are your input arguments that you will supply to "my_cost", and "in4, in5" inputs that are initialised once when you create the handle.

Then you can pass "my_cost" to another function if necessary and call it as:

```
[out1 out2 out3] = my_cost(in1, in2, in3);
```

Comment: Dear mikesapi, thanks for your answer but i am not sure if i get it correctly. So, following the example i stated above, i have:  function [x]=objfun(K)   @(x)f=[x(1)+x(2)]*K(x)  end. Now, i want to re-write the objective function as follows: @(x) f= M*K(x) where M=x(1)+x(2). What do i need to do?

Comment: My suggestion is to reformulate the way you want to do it. Create a function in a separate M-file that calculates the objective, given some input variables - then define a handle to it.